# Laravel Query Builder MySQL Join not returning values to datatable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, datatables

I am trying to join 2 MySQL tables for use in a Chumper Datatable. the two tables are called ec2_instance and aws_account and  are to be joined on their primary key id. I have the following statement using laravel query builder but my table is not displaying the results here is my statement :

```
$query = DB::table('ec2_instance')->join('aws_account', 'aws_account.id_ec2_instance', '=', 'ec2_instance.id')->select('ec2_instance.instance_id', 'ec2_instance.public_dns_name', 'ec2_instance.key_name','ec2_instance.instance_type','ec2_instance.launch_time','aws_account.aws_account_id')->get();
```

my table structures are as follows

aws_account

aws_account_id : varchar(100)
id : int(11) pk

ec2_instance

- id : int(11) pk

  - instance_id : varchar(30) unique
  - image_id : varchar(100)
  - private_dns_name : varchar(255)
  - public_dns_name : varchar(255)
  - key_name : varchar(255)
  - instance_type : varchar(255)
  - launch_time : varchar(255)
  - kernel_id : varchar(255)
  - subnet_id : varchar(255)
  - vpc_id : varchar(255)
  - private_ip_address : varchar(15)
  - public_ip_address : varchar(15)
  - architecture : varchar(20)
  - root_device_type : varchar(20)
  - root_device_name : varchar(50)
  - virtualization_type : varchar(50)

thanks

Comment: select `ec2_instance`.`instance_id`, `ec2_instance`.`public_dns_name`, `ec2_instance`.`key_name`, `ec2_instance`.`instance_type`, `ec2_instance`.`launch_time`, `aws_account`.`aws_account_id` from `ec2_instance` inner join `aws_account` on `aws_account`.`id_ec2_instance` = `ec2_instance`.`id` // check does this query run in phpmyadmin

Comment: @kamlesh.bar ran the above statement and I get the following error **bold**#1054 - Unknown column 'aws_account.id_ec2_instance' in 'on clause' **bold** what I need if this helps is to select the instance_id, public_dns_name, key_name, instance_type and launch_time from a table called ec2_instance join to a table called aws_account and select a column called aws_account_id in both tables I have an auto incrementing column called id the primary key in both tables and would probably join there thanks

Comment: seems like field id_ec2_instance not found in table aws_account. if you can paste table structure above i can help you out.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar that is correct there is no id_ec2_instance in aws_account it only has a column called id and aws_account_id ( the value I want to display ) the other thing I noticed is that aws_account_id is to be selected from aws_account not ec2_instance thanks

Comment: welcome. good to see your problem resolved.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar its not quite resolved yet that is just based on the sql statement you wrote I have not fixed it yet but fingers crossed

Comment: okay let me correct above laravel code with what you mention above.

Comment: $query = DB::table('ec2_instance')->join('aws_account', 'aws_account.id', '=', 'ec2_instance.id')->select('ec2_instance.instance_id', 'ec2_instance.public_dns_name', 'ec2_instance.key_name','ec2_instance.instance_type','ec2_instance.launch_time','aws_account.aws_account_id')->get();

Comment: one more thing if you can paste table structure above with primary key and foreign key it would be easy to give you exact answer. it's not still clear from both table which is common field ?

Comment: @kamlesh.bar have added table structure to question

Comment: okay so want to join both table with primary key id from both table than above posted code works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75274/discussion-between-richard-hewitt-and-kamlesh-bar).